# Extend ckeditor table plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to extend existing ckeditor table with custom container, it will have table header and personalization button, I try to convert my table to HTML add this div to figure but but it is constantly removed, I also tried to convert table and insert this container before inserting to model but it also didn't help me. Are there any ways to implement this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Ywl.png)

[Tried to change table html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNmki.png)

Comment: Could you include some of your code in the question? It will help us to answer you. Additionally it would help of you could expand upon what you are doing and what results you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: I am writing custom plugin which use ckeditor table, it draws table due to my config, I mean number of columns and rows. I trayed to convert my model table to html and change it but mutationOberver deletes my HTML. 
There is no something interesting in my code i just create table and do model.insertContent( table )